# How would I order a set of objects based on using <=> on an array attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a set of 2 or more objects that I'd like to order.  I had been doing it like this:

```
card.max_by{|strength| strength.score
```

Where score was an integer score I had computed given some arbitrary rules.  I knew this would be something I would refactor, so now I am doing so.  And the "clean" way to give a score to a hand is to give it an array of values like

```
foo.score = [9,3,nil,4]
```

And compare it to another hand which might have an array like

```
bar.score = [5,10,12,12]
```

And foo <=> bar would tell me that foo is the greater array and so it should be returned by max_by.  The problem is that max_by apparently won't make comparisons on arrays.  Is there another way I can do this to sort by the array value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just array-based ordering that you want (you really do want the spaceship operator) and you want to find the 'biggest' by sorting, then:

```
Hand = Struct.new(:score)

hands = [
 Hand.new([9,3,0,4]),
 Hand.new([8,8,8,8]),
 Hand.new([5,10,12,12]),
 Hand.new([1,99,99,99])
]

biggest = hands.sort_by(&:score).last
p biggest
#=> #<struct Hand score=[9, 3, 0, 4]>
```

If you really only need to find the largest hand, however, the following will be more efficient than ordering the entire array:

```
biggest = hands.inject do |max,hand|
  if (max.score <=> hand.score) == -1
    hand
  else
    max
  end
end
p biggest
#=> #<struct Hand score=[9, 3, 0, 4]>
```

**Edit**: Reading your comment, if you really need multiple values that match, I would do this:

```
Hand = Struct.new(:name,:score) do 
  MAX_SCORE_PART = 13 # 13 ranks in a suit
  def numeric_score
    value = 0
    score.each_with_index do |part,i|
      value += part.to_i * MAX_SCORE_PART**(score.length-i-1)
    end
    value
  end
end

hands = [
  Hand.new('Bob', [9,3,nil,4] ),
  Hand.new('Jim', [8,8,8,8]   ),
  Hand.new('Foo', [5,10,12,12]),
  Hand.new('Sam', [1,13,13,13]),
  Hand.new('Zak', [9,3,0,4]   ),
]

require 'pp'
by_score = hands.group_by(&:numeric_score)
pp by_score
#=> {20284=>
#=>   [#<struct Hand name="Bob", score=[9, 3, nil, 4]>,
#=>    #<struct Hand name="Zak", score=[9, 3, 0, 4]>],
#=>  19040=>[#<struct Hand name="Jim", score=[8, 8, 8, 8]>],
#=>  12843=>[#<struct Hand name="Foo", score=[5, 10, 12, 12]>],
#=>  4576=>[#<struct Hand name="Sam", score=[1, 13, 13, 13]>]}

pp by_score[by_score.keys.max]
#=> [#<struct Hand name="Bob", score=[9, 3, nil, 4]>,
#=>  #<struct Hand name="Zak", score=[9, 3, 0, 4]>]
```

*For an `inject`-based implementation:*

```
def numeric_score
  score.enum_for(:inject,0).with_index do |(val,part),i|
    val += part.to_i * MAX_SCORE_PART**(score.length-i-1)
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry, the "score" is the array, almost as if it were a sort_by in an database lookup, where if the first element of array 1 > first element of array 2, the first array is greater, if the first element is tied, then you look at the next element, etc.  I thought specifying <=> would clarify that, since it seems to me that that's how that operator works.  And I want the max "score", but if there are 5 objects and 2 have the same max score, I need them both.  My assumption that max_by works that way.

Comment: @JeremySmith My apologies, reading it a third time and focusing on the `<=>` I think I understand. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks so much, no need for apologies given how much you give to this site!

Comment: @JeremySmith I edited my answer one more time with a simple way to gather multiple matching max values.

Answer (score 2):

`max_by` works with array "attributes" just fine:

```
# Phrogz's example
Hand = Struct.new(:score)
hands = [
 Hand.new([9,3,0,4]),
 Hand.new([8,8,8,8]),
 Hand.new([5,10,12,12]),
 Hand.new([1,99,99,99])
]
#
hands.max_by(&:score)    # => #<struct Hand score=[9, 3, 0, 4]>
```

However if the arrays can contain nils or other values that don't compare with each other, `<=>` could return nil and `max_by` could fail.